# Get part of string after a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get a part of a string this is the string:

```
"#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Facebook"
```

I would like to get the `data-count` value this is what I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s[i]);
    console.log(s[i].substring(0, s[i].indexOf('data-count="')));
}
```

but then it stops at the part I want to get how can I achieve it to get the value of data-count?

Comment: Can you tell us what is s?

Comment: If the string originally comes from an HTML/DOM element/node, then you could just use `$(node).data("count")`

Comment: is it a string or an html element? are you trying to get that attrbitute?

Comment: it is an string where I try to strip out the data-count attribute

Comment: should be an element - user $( "youElement" ).data( "count")

Comment: sorry my point about thge string is - is it just a flat string as you have shown or a string of a html element - in which case you can turn it into a jquery object by doing `$(stringOfHtml)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue using your method of `.indexOf` and `.substring`:

```js
var s = '"#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="facebook" onclick=...';

var searchFor = 'data-count="';

var startPos = s.indexOf(searchFor) + searchFor.length;  // add on the length to get the end
var endPos = s.indexOf('"', startPos);        // find the next " after data-count=

alert(s.substring(startPos, endPos));         // extract the string
```

---

An alternate would be to let jquery *parse* the html for you, even though it starts as a string, you can convert it to a jquery object by wrapping in `<div .. >`, eg:

```js
var s = '"#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="facebook" onclick=...';
alert($("<div " + s + "></div>").data("count"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

while slightly less code, it will be slower if you have lots (10,000+) strings to parse.

Comment: what if the value contains an escaped "?

Comment: and if the data-count value is not always 12 char

Comment: the "data-count=" value is the bit being searched for, so will always be 12, as requested in the question, explicitly "data-count=", even says in the question "a *specific* value".

Comment: @Sireini that could be changed to key.length where key is the string.

Comment: Added a 'searchFor' / key to make it more reusable - of course you could pass this in as a parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with splitting this string by whitespace, then finding proper element with `find` and cleaning it up with `replace`:

```
s.split(' ').find(v => v.contains('data-count')).replace(/.*?"([^"]+")/, '$1')
```

or at the end split by `=` and remove `"` characters:

```
s.split(' ').find(v => v.contains('data-count')).split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, '')
```

Comment: It would be better if instead of contains, you use starts with.
Also, what if there is a space between = and the value or between data-count and = ?

Comment: @KristjanKica OPs question was to search for the *specific* value `data-count="`, no other what-ifs need apply.